# Store in Array List two child classes of the same parent class

Tags: java

I have a parent class User with only Attributes Username and Password. Also i have two Child Classes Customer and Admin. Can i store to the same ArrayList both customers and admins? I need to use the username and password attributes to authenticate them for the log in.

Comment: Yes, just create an Arraylist of Users. This will strip the knowledge of any fields specific to children when accessing the list however, but you shouldn't have a problem with accessing username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes , you can make an Arraylist of User class and when you call the constructor you can use any one of the three classes

see this tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm

Comment: Links don't qualify as answers. What if the link dies? You can summarize the information found in the link as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can . just see the ex:

### Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    public void makeNoise(){
    System.out.println("Animal making Noise");
    }
    public void eat(){
    System.out.println("Animal is eating");
    }
    public void walk(){
    System.out.println("Animal is walking");
    }
 }
```

### Dog.java

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
    @Override
    public void makeNoise(){
    System.out.println("Barking");
    }
}
```

### Tiger.java

```
  public class Tiger extends Animal{

     @Override
     public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Raoring...");
     }
  }
```

And I am Accessing the Those Parent and Child class objects through
Main class

### Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Animal[] a1= new Animal[3];
    
    a1[0]=new Dog();
    a1[1]=new Cat();
    a1[2]=new Tiger();
    
    for(Animal ar:a1) {
        ar.makeNoise();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please note the difference between Array (your answer) and ArrayList (the question).
By the way : what is the relation User (from the question) to Animals ?